# Solr: get dynamic field names

Tags: solr

Data in my Solr core looks like this:

```
[
 {"id" : "1",
  "color" : "Red",
  "prop_1" : "a"
 },
 {"id" : "2",
  "color" : "Blue",
  "prop_1" : "a",
  "prop_2" : "b"
 }
 {"id" : "3",
  "color" : "Red",
  "prop_1" : "x"
  "prop_3" : "y",
  "prop_4" : "z"
 }
]
```

`id, color` are static fields, `prop_` fields are dynamic.

I can get all the dynamic fields by using this query:

```
select?wt=csv&rows=0&facet=true&fl=prop_*
```

How to get all the dynamic fields (distinct would be a plus) from the documents, where color=Red?

I want to get `prop_1, prop_3, prop_4`.